# Is peer-to-peer a variation of client-server architectural pattern?

Tags: architecture, architectural-patterns, client-server

According to Software Engineering: Theory and Practice book by Pfleeger and Atlee, Peer-to-peer architectural style is different than Client-Server architectural pattern. But in Mocrsoft's Microsoft Application Architecture Guide, 2nd Edition, it has been stated that peer-to-peer is a variant of client-server ([link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/msp-n-p/ee658117(v=pandp.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)). Can anyone please clarify this to me and which is correct?

Comment: You can regard P2P as C/S where C and S can switch roles.

Comment: @MartinMaat indeed ! but roles can’t always be switched. Would you say in more general terms that symmetry is a variant of asymmetry ?

Comment: @Christophe No I would not. I followed the link and it appears it isn't that crazy a statement in context. P2P is listed among "variations on the client/server style", which does not mean "a kind of" but rather "something slightly different". They specifically mention the switching of roles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the characteristics you are looking for to asses how close they are.

Microsoft’s article sees P2P style as an extension of C/S in view of communication potentially, so from the view point of communication development techniques:

> the P2P style allows the client and server to swap their roles in
>   order to distribute and synchronize files and information across
>   multiple clients. It extends the client/server style through multiple
>   responses to requests, shared data, resource discovery, and resilience
>   to removal of peers.

However,  most C/S systems do not offer symmetric clients. Sometimes C/S style was even chosen because clients and servers cannot be swapped. So there must be something else than just symmetry vs. asymetry of communications that could matter.

If instead of looking at **communication** (Microsoft’s article view) you look at **control**, you’ll view the two styles as very different. Because most C/S implement a variant of Master/servant relationship (central control) whereas P2P implement relationships of equals.

If you are in networks and are looking at the **topology**, you’ll also see two very different picture: you have for C/S a tree like shape, whereas the P2P has a kind of mesh.

So in general, I would not say that it’s a variant.

Answer (score 0):

What makes the client "the client" and the server "the server" is several fold:

1. the server makes itself available, for example, via DNS registration
2. the client know or must be told of the server (e.g. it knows or is otherwise told the server's name, and then learns the server's IP address via DNS or directory/search services)
3. the client asks the server to establish a connection (the server learns of the client at this step)
4. the client requests, e.g. makes a command to or inquiry of, the server
5. the server responds to the client

The client can (1) initiate connection, and, (2) initiates request/response patterns; whereas the server cannot do these things, and that also means the client doesn't need a host/domain name or to publish its IP address.

By using a trick of making a long running (and say abstract) request from the client to the server, after a connection is established, the server can effectively initiate communication with the client, and request/response can be reversed — server making requests and client responding.  If the client wants, it can interrupt a long running request and perform a new specific request, taking back control of the request/response pair.

In true peer-to-peer, we presume that either side can initiate the connection (meaning the peers have to know of each other (or of a directory service) before hand), and then also, that either side can initiate a request/response, or just simply send a one-way message.  These effectively eliminate the asymmetry in client-server.

Though more awkward, peer-to-peer can be formed by using a pair of client-server roles — where each node plays both client and server roles.  Then, either side can initiate connection, and either side can initiate request/response.

Peer-to-Peer may be a validation of client-server (not sure what that means necessarily); however, peer-to-peer does not *require* client-server, which is an important distinction.

Client-server has restrictions for a purpose, so by using the term client-server do we mean those important restrictions, or, the union of the broader capabilities by and implementation requirements of client and server.  If the latter, then I suppose we can consider peer-to-peer and extension or variant of client-server (otherwise not).